# reactstrap tooltip dynamic id

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am developing a react application and using reactstrap.

I am using Tooltip Component of reactstrap which requires a target attribute, a value of target element's id. This id is being geneated dynamically and seems reactstrap tooltip doesn't like it.

Component looks like:

**MovieCard.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Col, Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, CardText, Button, Tooltip } from 'reactstrap';
import { LimitedTextTitle } from '../custom-styled/CustomStyledComponents';

class MovieCard extends Component {  

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle () {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { imdbID, Title, Year, Rated, Plot, Country, Poster } = this.props.movie;

    return (
  <Col md="4">
    <Card>
      <CardImg
        top
        width="100%"
        src={Poster}
        alt="blah"
      />
    </Card>
    <CardBody>
      <CardTitle>
        <LimitedTextTitle id={imdbID}>
          {`${Title} - (${Year})`}
        </LimitedTextTitle>
        <Tooltip placement='top' target={imdbID} isOpen={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggle}>
          {Title}
        </Tooltip>
      </CardTitle>
      <CardSubtitle>{`Rated: ${Rated} Country: ${Country}`}</CardSubtitle>
      <CardText>{Plot}</CardText>
      <Button>Read More</Button>
    </CardBody>
  </Col>
);
  }
}

MovieCard.propTypes = {
  movie: PropTypes.object.isRequired // eslint-disable-line
};

export default MovieCard;
```

Any suggestions?

react vesion 16.2.0

reactstrap 5.0.0-alpha.4

Comment: Looks ok. Do you have any error/warning in console ? or is the tooltip not appearing for only some items ? or is the imdb id is null/empty ?

Comment: imdbID isnot null, the error in console says, target is undefined, though if i remove tooltips and run the code above, it generates the with id attribute populated.

Comment: wow.. can you show me the render of `LimitedTextTitle` ?

Comment: https://github.com/priyankthakkar/open-movie-web.git here is the source code. refer to branch 'landing-page'

Comment: You have not rendered your id anywhere. You have passed it as a prop to the `styled-component` but it is not rendered on the page. Wrap it in a div/span and pass the `id` to it.

Comment: your tooltip id should not contain special characters and should not be empty. make sure it is string.

Answer (score 9):

Was dealing with a similar problem.

Adding the code as an answer because i cannot add a comment above...

Hope it will help you or anyone else who will come across this question.

Description:
Use reactstrap tooltip for elements that are getting generated dynamically.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Button, Tooltip } from 'reactstrap';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  toggle = targetName => {
    if (!this.state[targetName]) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [targetName]: {
          tooltipOpen: true
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [targetName]: {
          tooltipOpen: !this.state[targetName].tooltipOpen
        }
      });
    }
  };

  isToolTipOpen = targetName => {
    return this.state[targetName] ? this.state[targetName].tooltipOpen : false;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((x, i) => (
          <div key={`div-${i}`}>
            <Button color="link" id={`btn-${i}`}>
              {x}
            </Button>
            <Tooltip
              placement="right"
              isOpen={this.isToolTipOpen(`btn-${i}`)}
              target={`btn-${i}`}
              toggle={() => this.toggle(`btn-${i}`)}>
              Hello world!
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

react: 16.9.0

reactstrap: 8.0.1

https://codesandbox.io/embed/angry-taussig-fup7i?fontsize=14

Answer (score 4):

EUREKA I GOT IT!!! Building on Meir Keller's answer, there's no need to check if that state for the tooltip already exist. If it doesn't exist, it's `false` by default...

So long as state is defined, even if it's an empty state, this works.

This is using reactstrap's Popover, but it's the same concept.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Container, Row, Col, Input, Button, Popover } from 'reactstrap';

class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  toggle = (target) => {
    // console.log(typeof target) // make sure this is a string
    this.setState({
      ...state,
      [target]: !this.state[target]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
      {["Hello", "Greetings"].map((name) => (

      <Row>
      <Fragment>
          <Button id={name} type="button">{name}</Button>
          <Popover placement="right" 
          isOpen={this.state[`${name}`]} 
          target={name}
          toggle={() => this.toggle(`${name}`)}>
          <PopoverBody>
            You've got mail. Did you know?
            </PopoverBody>
            </Popover>
            </Fragment>
      </Row>
      ))}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Create a new component in modular or component directory and paste this code**

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "reactstrap";

const TooltipItem = props => {
    const { position='top', id } = props;
    const [tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => setTooltipOpen(!tooltipOpen);

    return (
        <span>
      <span id={"tooltip-" + id}>
            {props.children}
      </span>
      <Tooltip
          placement={position}
          isOpen={tooltipOpen}
          target={"tooltip-" + id}
          toggle={toggle}
      >
          {props.title}
      </Tooltip>
    </span>
    );
};


export default TooltipItem;
```

**Now import and use this tooltip component**

```
import TooltipItem from "../Tooltip";

 <TooltipItem id={'edit' + data.id} title={'Edit Store'}>
    <i className="fas fa-edit pointer" onClick={() => this.onEditClick(data)}/>
  </TooltipItem>
```

Comment: You saved me hours. This works with ```<UncontrolledTooltip>``` as well. kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I will Like to add an answer for it as already many people have mentioned many ways to deal with the problem.
But `reactStrap` works perfectly fine, mistakes most of the beginners are doing that while creating `id` they are using *special characters* like:

`- _ / @` and it can even be a `space`

**Just keep the id a very simple combination of chars and numbers reactstrap will work totally fine**

Answer (score 0):

New component `UncontrolledTooltip` will solve the problem. Just use

```
 <UncontrolledTooltip
   placement="right"
   target={`btn-${i}`}
 >
   {props.title}
 </UncontrolledTooltip>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the actual context.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions and was still having trouble with Reactstrap Tooltip crashing when the target element is not in the Dom.

I combined a couple other solutions that people posted and this is the only way it worked for me. Conditional rendering FTW.

```
const ElementWithTooltip = ({
    dynamicIdentifier, // string, number, w/e
}): ReactElement => {
    // Target element state.
    const [isTargetReady, setIsTargetReady] = useState(false);
    
    // Target element ref.
    const tooltipRef = useRef(null);
 
    // Hook to recognize that the target is ready.
    useEffect(() => {
        const targetElement = tooltipRef.current;
        if (targetElement) {
            setIsTargetReady(true);
        }
      }, [tooltipRef.current]);

    // TSX.
    return (
        <>
            <span ref={tooltipRef}>This is the target element</span>
            {isTargetReady && <UncontrolledTooltip autohide={false} target={tooltipRef}>
                Tooltippy text stuff
            </UncontrolledTooltip>}
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `imdbID` most probably is starting with digit i.e. `123abcdefghijklmno1234567890`

Remember that tooltips can't work in that case when ID starts with a number i.e. the Tooltip's target cannot start with an integer.

all you need to do here is, change this:

```
<CardTitle>
    <LimitedTextTitle id={imdbID}>
      {`${Title} - (${Year})`}
    </LimitedTextTitle>
    <Tooltip placement='top' target={imdbID} isOpen={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggle}>
      {Title}
    </Tooltip>
</CardTitle>
```

to this:

```
<CardTitle>
    <LimitedTextTitle id={`movie-${imdbID}`}>
      {`${Title} - (${Year})`}
    </LimitedTextTitle>
    <Tooltip placement='top' target={`movie-${imdbID}`} isOpen={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggle}>
      {Title}
    </Tooltip>
</CardTitle>
```

You can avoid using state by simply switching to `UncontrolledTooltip` which handles all the toggle itself without asking you to handle that explicitly, like:

```
<CardTitle>
    <LimitedTextTitle id={`movie-${imdbID}`}>
      {`${Title} - (${Year})`}
    </LimitedTextTitle>
    <UncontrolledTooltip placement='top' target={`movie-${imdbID}`}>
      {Title}
    </UncontrolledTooltip>
</CardTitle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering dynamic content in tooltip in react js is very simple.
Use ReactTooltip.
For full understanding check below example.
Here I am adding requestId in tooltip as dynamically.

```
{
completedTransactions.map((item, id) => (
<tr key={id + 1}>
  <td>{id + 1}</td>
  <td>
    <span data-tip={item.requestId} data-for="registerTip">
      {item.TransactionId}
    </span>
    <ReactTooltip id="registerTip" place="top" />
  </td>
  <td>{item.groupName}</td>
  <td>{item.purposeName}</td>
  <td>{dateFormat(item.update, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm tt")}</td>
 </tr>
```

));
}